Waves, energy and matter
What is the physical reason why a wave (mechanical or electromagnetic) can transport only energy and not matter?
Is it perhaps because if a wave could transport matter, then a larger amount of energy (produced by the wave itself) would be necessary?

A wave is just a mathematical construct that happens to be convenient when describing some types of matter and energy. Can you be more specific?

I mean, why a wave (intended as a perturbation of the mean of propagation) can transport only energy and not matter?

How do you differentiate energy and matter? Most physicists don't, since $E=mc^2$.

I work in a classical context; I have not so much knowledge of relativity.

However, most surprisingly, the question challenges the definition of waves themselves.

I'm not a physicist, and I'm not sure how the physicists will vote on this one; but IMO, instead of saying that a wave transports energy, I think it might be closer to the truth to say that a wave is energy.
Drop a pebble into a pond. Some people will tell you that the surface waves that radiate outward from that event are a "disturbance" that propagates outward. OK, but what has been "disturbed" in that case? And, how did you disturb it? You disturbed the local water level, and you did it by adding energy. You created a higher energy state that radiates outward in all directions as "ripples" which are alternating variations in the potential energy and the kinetic energy of the water particles.

This is fairly close to right. It would be useful if the question specified what kind of wave, but in the general sense this isn't wrong.

We like to deal with abstractions that make easier to explain reality. For example, there is no mechanical waves in an idealized rigid body. Any movement at any of its points is instantaneously propagated. On the other extreme, a system of non interacting particles also doesn't have waves. Particles travel freely when kicked by any external source.
Mechanical waves results for more realistic physical systems, where forces at some points propagate through the system by interactions between its elements.


What is the physical reason why a wave (mechanical or electromagnetic) can transport only energy and not matter?

An electromagnetic wave, by definition, describes wave behavior related to photons.  Photons, of course, are not matter, just energy.  So an EM wave cannot describe motion by matter.
However, we do associate waves with matter in the form of de Broglie waves.  Also called matter waves, these have been experimentally verified to exist, nearly 100 years ago.
So matter transport associated with waves is a real thing, and EM waves simply cannot transport matter.
